# How to calculate width of multiple lines of UITextview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel, uitextview, lines

I have a `UITextView` that has a maximum number of four lines. I want to put `UILabels` behind each line, covering only however much text there is for the respective line.

So do any of you fine coders have any ideas as to how I would calculate each line's width?

Comment: Google `NSString UIKit extensions`, then <ctrl> + <F>, search for `size`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one

```
UIFont *font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f];

UILabel *yourLabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 80)];
yourLabel.numberOfLines=4;
yourLabel.text=@"Hello\nHulo\nMe\nyou";

CGSize labelSize = [yourLabel.text sizeWithFont:font
                              constrainedToSize:yourLabel.frame.size
                                  lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
CGFloat singleLineHeight = labelSize.height/yourLabel.numberOfLines;


[self.view addSubview:yourLabel];
```

A single line height will be about 21.

```
NSLog(@"single line height is %f",singleLineHeight);
```

**For text View follow this code**

```
UITextView *yourView=[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 20)];
yourView.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f];
yourView.text    = @"Hello \nmy\n Friend\n Hru? ";

CGSize textViewSize = [yourView.text sizeWithFont:yourView.font
                       constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(yourView.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX)
                           lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];

[yourView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, textViewSize.width, textViewSize.height)];

[self.view addSubview:yourView];

NSLog(@"single line height is %f",yourView.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: This works perfectly to get the height. What can I do extra to get the width of every line?

Comment: you means you want to get both height and width of single line

Comment: I think I figured out how I can get that info. Thanks, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: For anyone who's interested, the way to get the width of a string is to use - (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font .